# Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I am currently using the a query search from the Wikipedia api in my async task to get data. Everything is working fine, but the wikipedia query is returning a number as a key in json which I cant convert to a String programmatically.

Wikipedia query url: [Wikipedia query](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Felix)

Async Task:

```
Log.i(Config.TAG, result);
String query = data.getString("query");
JSONObject pagesObj = new JSONObject(query);
String pages = pagesObj.getString("pages");
JSONObject page = new JSONObject(pages);
String pageID = (String) page.names().get(0);
String message = null;
String title = null;
    if (Integer.parseInt(pageID) == -1){
        title = "No User found";
        message = "It seems that this User does not have a Wikipedia Article yet.";
    } else {
        JSONObject part = new JSONObject(pageID);
        title = part.getString("title");
        message = part.getString("extract");
    }
```

Error log:

```
05-09 16:38:10.650 25295-25323/org.mypackage.name W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:163)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
05-09 16:38:10.651 25295-25323/org.mypackage.name W/System.err:     at org.mypackage.name.classes.GetContent.doInBackground(GetContent.java:117)
    at org.mypackage.name.classes.GetContent.doInBackground(GetContent.java:26)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
05-09 16:38:10.652 25295-25323/org.mypackage.name W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
05-09 16:38:10.653 25295-25323/org.mypackage.name W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Is there a way to convert the given Integer to a String or is even something wrong in my code?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the better way is to use jackson?
Something like that

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(data);
title = node.get("query").get("pages").get(0).get("title");
message = node.get("query").get("pages").get(0).get("message")
```

Comment: Thanks. Was much easier than I thought. I just had to replace .get(0) in your code with my pageID